# Make Highcharts' setExtremes off tick with two yAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to set minimum and maximum of yAxis of a Highcharts' chart. And I do NOT want the minimum and maximum to round to the ticks.

Highcharts documentation offers an example, which works great:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/axis-setextremes-off-ticks/

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
    yAxis = chart.yAxis[0];

    yAxis.options.startOnTick = false;
    yAxis.options.endOnTick = false;

    chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(40, 210);
```

But when I do it with two y-axis, it doesn't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/4kLyf04a/

The minimum and maximum that chart uses are not what I set in the code. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [alignTicks](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks) parameter as false.